# Adding line break to link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a code that needs to be split into two lines so it looks nice.  However when I try:

```
link_to "Some Text<br />Here",url_path
```

it will output the HTML too, even if I use html.html_safe like so:

```
html = ""
html += link_to "Some Text<br />Here",url_path
html.html_safe
```

How can I make it so "Here" will appear on a new line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
link_to "Some Text<br />Here".html_safe, url_path
```

Answer (score 19):

A trick most Rails developers don't know is that [`link_to` accepts a block](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.8rc1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M006605):

```
<%= link_to(url_path) do %>
  Some Text
  <br />
  Here
<% end %>
```

Comment: though this does not address the html_safe issue

Comment: There a no problems with `html_safe`. You can just throw everything into the block.

Comment: This answer is a bit better IMO. If the link_to text had any user inputed data generated dynamically, this would be the safer bet.